# How important is the portrait-only mode for long ipad form?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

We are launching a long ipad form (quote-and-buy journey). it is designed primarily for landscape.

How important is it to be optimised for portrait?

Currently, the thinking is - launch landscape first & portrait optimised after..

Comment: It might depend on the content of these forms. For instance if it's complex typing you have to do then it might be better in landscape mode as the on-screen keyboard is possibly easier to type on than the portrait one (that's only a hypothesis on my part though), but if it's just checkboxes & dropdowns then the keyboard isn't used as much so the smaller sized reduced one may be sufficient. However, you've tagged this `responsive-design` so it's going to work on all devices regardless of orientation. What about retina layouts? iPad mini etc? They'll all get it in one form or another regardless.

Comment: Have you got any analytics of your users? That might help you make your decision.

Comment: This question can only yield a subjective answer.  There are too many factors to take into account to answer with any sort of objectivity.

Answer (score 2):

For long forms, portrait is preferred, because:

1. More form is visible in portrait mode than landscape.
2. More fields are visible in portrait mode with on-screen keyboard on.
3. Easy to hold and type while doing data entry.

Once we had a similar problem, and after a research, we came to this conclusion that, for bigger data entry forms, using portrait is better than landscape. This applies for any tablet device.